# Creating CA, Intermediate CA and Sub CAs via the EJBCA API

Tags: ejbca

I want to create a CA, Intermediate CA and Sub CAs via the EJBCA API. I looked at the EJBCA interface but I don't see methods to do this. Am I missing something?

http://ejbca.org/older_releases/ejbca_4_0/htdocs/ws/org/ejbca/core/protocol/ws/client/gen/EjbcaWS.html

Answer (score 0):

Your link is for a quite old EJBCA release (v4.0, as opposed to 6.10.x for latest Community and 6.15.x for latest Enterprise). The [latest EJBCA WS API](https://www.ejbca.org/docs/ws/org/ejbca/core/protocol/ws/client/gen/EjbcaWS.html) provides the method [createCA](https://www.ejbca.org/docs/ws/org/ejbca/core/protocol/ws/client/gen/EjbcaWS.html#createCA(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20long,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.List,%20java.util.List)) to create a Root or Subordinate CA. According to documentation, the created CA is a a Root CA if the `signedByCAId` argument is `1`, else a subordinate.